# Count in dimensional array and php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to display the number of pass and fail students (pass if the score is greater than 50 and fail otherwise) in this code.

```html
<?php
$students= array(
  array (100, 'Ali',78),
   array (200, 'Khalied',50),
   array (300, 'Fatema',44),
   array (400, 'Sumaya',80),
);

  ?>


<table border="1">
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Score</th>
  </tr>
  
  <?php

  foreach($students as $student){
  echo'<tr>';
  foreach($student as $item){
   echo "<td>$item</td>";
 }
 echo '</tr>';
}
$filled_array=$students[0];
 $count=count($filled_array);
 echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: My problem I can not print The number of students who pass and fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$students   = array(
                array (100, 'Ali',78),
                array (200, 'Khalied',50),
                array (300, 'Fatema',44),
                array (400, 'Sumaya',80),
            );
$passed     = $failed   = 0;
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($students as $student) {
        $getMarks   = $student[2];
        $getMarks>50 ? $passed++ : $failed++;
        echo '<tr><td>'.implode("</td><td>", $student).'</td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
Passed : <?php echo $passed; //prints 2 ?><br>
Failed : <?php echo $failed; //prints 2 ?>
```

above is your required snippet.

firstly, improved performance by avoiding the loop and by adding `implode` in place of loop.

initialized two vars `passed` and `failed` with value `0`, and within the loop conditionally incrementing those `(if marks greater than 50)`

Comment: Sir what is you mean in (implode) this is the first time I use it

Comment: @Hamda, it is an in-built function, which accepts two parameters, 1. string to be imploded(added in between). 2. array (in which values has to be added)

Comment: Yah I understand you, Thankes

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is restructure your students array by adding keys to it.

```
<?php
    $students= array(
        array ('ID'=>100, 'Name'=>'Ali','Score'=>78),
        array ('ID'=>200, 'Name'=>'Khalied','Score'=>50),
        array ('ID'=>300, 'Name'=>'Fatema','Score'=>44),
        array ('ID'=>400, 'Name'=>'Sumaya','Score'=>80),
    );
?>
```

Then you can modify your loop to track the scores based on those keys with an additional array.

```
<?php
    $resultsArray = array('Pass'=>0, 'Fail'=>0);
    foreach($students as $student){
        if( $student['Score'] > 50 ){ // PASS
             $resultsArray['Pass']++;
        } else { // FAIL
             $resultsArray['Fail']++;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can not accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
$filled_array=$students[0];
$count=count($filled_array);
echo $count;
```

`$students[0]` is the array `[100, 'Ali',78]`, so counting it is just going to return 3 every time.

Since you are already looping over the list of students, just add a counter before the loop and increment for each passing student.

```
$passing_count = 0;                // start at zero
foreach($students as $student) {
    if ($student[2] > 50) {        // student[2] is the grade
        $passing_count++;          // increment count if passing
    }
    echo'<tr>';
    foreach($student as $item) {
        echo "<td>$item</td>";
    }
}
```

If you want to find the number of failing students, you can just subtract `$passing_count` (passing students) from `count($students)` (all students) after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the pass/fail as you iterate through the students, and display the result at the end, like so:

```
<?php
$students= array(
  array (100, 'Ali',78),
   array (200, 'Khalied',50),
   array (300, 'Fatema',44),
   array (400, 'Sumaya',80),
);

?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Score</th>
  </tr>
<?php
    $fail = 0;
    $pass = 0;
  foreach($students as $student){
      ($student[2] <= 50 ? $fail++ : $pass++);
  echo'<tr>';
  foreach($student as $item){
   echo "<td>$item</td>";
 }
 echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
echo 'Pass: ' . $pass;
echo '<br />';
echo 'Fail: ' . $fail;
?>
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qjxt-i6yk)